# quiero cambiar la extension de un archivo teniendo su nombre y ruta

Tags: python

lo que necesito es yo ya teniendo el nombre del archivo con su extension y su ruta, cambiar la extension del archivo por otra

intenté esto:

```
if quality_option.get() == choices[1]: 
      os.replace(folder_name+titulo2+".mp4",folder_name+titulo2+".mp3" )
```

pero me lanza este error:

```
OSError: [WinError 123] El nombre de archivo, el nombre de directorio o la sintaxis de la etiqueta del volumen no son correctos: 'D:/Phoenix (ft. Cailin Russo and Chrissy Costanza) | Worlds 2019 - League of Legends.mp4' -> 'D:/Phoenix (ft. Cailin Russo and Chrissy Costanza) | Worlds 2019 - League of Legends.mp3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que te está fallando son dos cosas:

1. La funcion que estas mandando llamar: Creo que lo que estas buscando es `os.rename`.
2. Tus direcciones: Se deben poner `/` para navegar entre carpetas.

Así lo tienes:

```
if quality_option.get() == choices[1]: 
  os.replace(folder_name+titulo2+".mp4",folder_name+titulo2+".mp3" )
```

Así debe de estar

```
if quality_option.get() == choices[1]: 
  os.rename(folder_name+"/"+titulo2+".mp4",folder_name+"/"+titulo2+".mp3")
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.